# Can packer with vmware-vmx connect to esxi?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vmware, packer, esxi

Is it possible for the `vmware-vmx` provisioner of packer to connecto to an esxi server? The documentation (https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-vmx.html) does seem toe lack the variables `remote_*` which are available in https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-iso.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not supported by `vmware-vmx`.

Comment: I would want to build a base image and then run some different ansible configuration scripts on it depending on some configuration values. Do you see any possibility to reuse the initially built vm on esxi as a cache to speed up the entire build process?

Comment: No, not except running a "local" `vmware-vmx` build with nested virtualisation and VMware Workstation in an VM on the ESXi host. (I think it should be fairly easy to extend the `vmware-vmx` builder with remote capabilities if you are fairly proficient developer, but it will take some time)

Answer (score 3):

We've developed a new Packer plugin for exactly this task: remote incremental builds using native vSphere API.
Check out at https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/packer-builder-vsphere